# Adding more than one admin to Azure mobile services app

Tags: c#, windows, azure-mobile-services

I am building an application using azure mobile services, where I have used azure authentication services for user authentication. Each user can store some of their information. I want to add more than one admin who can manipulate the information of all user when needed. I also want to provide admins a separate front-end. Is it possible to implement. If possible kindly provide me some resources.

Comment: Do you mean an Admin for your Mobile Service (i.e. access to the Windows Azure Portal) or admin access within the context of your application?

Comment: not Windows Azure portal. Every user must authenticate and can see or update only the information entered by himself. I want to give 2-3 person admin privilege who can see or modify all information of any user from the app without going to portal.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Services on it's own doesn't have any concept of what an Admin is in your application.  For that reason, you'd have to design the admin system yourself.  You can do this in a few different ways including:

- Create an Admin only app that the admin's use and send the Mobile Service Master Key over in the headers.  This will make the user.level property return "Admin" while user's who are just authenticated to your app will have a user.level property of "Authenticated".  You can use this in your server scripts to basically say "If admin, do THIS, otherwise if authenticated, do THAT".
- You can create a Role table in your database and check if the user making the request is an admin for reach request.  If so, you can then use similar server side logic above to perform specific logic for the admin vs the non-admin.
- If you know the specific user IDs of people who will be admin's, you can just check against the user making the request in your server side logic (the advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require an admin only app or an additional check against the database to see what the user's role is).

Again, Mobile Services doesn't have a concept of an admin as far as your users go (only the sense that if the Master Key is sent in the request is "from an admin") so that's something you have to put in place yourself.

Comment: Actually I am trying to build an enterprise app. So for Enterprise end I can make an admin only app but the problem is both app should access  the same table and I have modified the insert and view script(Server side) so that only authenticated user can see and modify his information only. Can you tell me how can I make those admin only apps so that they can modify any users information.

Comment: In your Admin only app, you need to send the master key over as a header with each request (header name is X-ZUMO-MASTER as seen here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj677200.aspx).  Since you've locked the tables down so they require authenticated users, your admins will also have to login as users.  However, in your scripts you can then check the user.level property.  If it's "Authenticated" then you know it's a normal user.  If it's "Admin" you know they're an admin.  Just do different logic in your scripts based off that user.level property.